# Firestore function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function:

```
var Ref = db.collection('Test').doc('Document');

function fire() {
    var getDoc = Ref.get()
     .then(doc => {
         if(doc.exists){
            return doc.data().Num
         }else{
             return
         }

     })
     .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting document', err);
    });
}

console.log(fire()); // undefined
```

How could I get this working so it returns the document from firestore? I need a function for what I am trying to do, I'm aware that you can do this regularly without one.

Comment: Use `promises`, `async/await`. These are asynchronous calls.

Comment: @Shubham I've tried using async/await and I can't access them at global scope. Would you mind posting a code sample? (I might be doing something wrong)

Comment: Your `fire` function is `asynchronous` and your console.log is running synchronously. Use `async/await`.

Comment: @randomSoul would you mind posting a code sample? I'm very inexperienced with async and node as whole

Comment: `(async () => { function fire() { var doc = await Ref.get(); if(doc.exists) { return doc.data().Num;} return null;}})();`. Put the code in `try...catch` block to trap any errors if encountered.

Comment: Overall I'm not having any luck with async

Comment: @LandonG - What error do you get? See - http://collabedit.com/eut6f.

Comment: `var getDoc = await Ref.get(); SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`, also `err` part has a red underline which will throw an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194031/discussion-between-randomsoul-and-landon-g).